# create clean url from ID but show name instead of ID

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to create an htaccess file for clean urls

I have ID and articlename columns in my database

I am trying to creat clean urls from
this : localhost/article.php?ID=50
to this localhost/article/articlename/

Is that possible with htaccess file?

I have that code in my article.php file

```
$article=$_REQUEST['article'];
$getArticle = $db->get_rows("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ID=$article");
```

I have that in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: ubiquitous - what have **you** tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to use an Apache rewrite to convert a clean URL to a numeric database ID, so the best way to accomplish this would be to add a new column to your database for the clean URL value and use that as the query string value instead.

Then the only thing you need to change in your code is to use the new column in the SQL query where clause instead of ID.

Comment: Ok I got it. So what I have to do if I have another column like "article_owner". I mean how to write the query for that? ID is unique but article_owner is not. Sorry I am confused. ex: localhost/articleID/article_owner

Comment: Do you have a column for article title? If so you can generate the clean URL based on that. So if the title is "My interesting story" the URL would localhost/my-interesting-story. Then when you enter your articles you should generate and store this as a separate column and just in case there is ever a duplicate title you could add a number at the end like localhost/my-interesting-story1